# DevExpress XAF - Test if an object is registred before executing code in ViewController

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, xaf

I'm developing using DevExpress XAF, my problem is a little bit tricky, in short, when I save my class I make changes in other classes based on the data provided, I realized this with a controller that executes code when I close the detail view, the problem is that there is a scenario that does not meet my needs, here is it:

When I open a detail view already existing and that I modify some data, when I close the window, the program displays a window of confirmation ("do you want to register?) when I click on no, normally my view controller will not do anything because I refused to change my class data

Finally here is my question: How to test in my view controller if the object was registered or not before proceeding to the change and execute my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *register*, I think you mean *save*.

You can use the `ObjectSpace.GetObjectsToSave()` method to obtain a list of objects which will be saved when `ObjectSpace.CommitChanges()` is called. You can then determine whether View.CurrentObject is in this list.

Alternatively you could use the `ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged` event. Something like this.

```
public class MyViewController : ObjectViewController<DetailView, Contact> {
    protected override void OnActivated() {
        base.OnActivated();
        ObjectSpace.ObjectChanged += ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged;
    }

    void ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged(object sender, ObjectChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Object == View.CurrentObject) {
            // execute your business logic
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivated() {
        base.OnDeactivated();
        ObjectSpace.ObjectChanged -= ObjectSpace_ObjectChanged;
    }
}
```

See [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T266852/) for a Support Center discussion of a similar request.